# A storage bin thingy for Repl.it projects

Tags: python, flask

I have a Repl.it account that I use for my projects, and I don't really want to make a new api for storage every time, I've seen some like EasyDB and Jsonstore (I use Jsonstore in the background as storage here) but it doesn't have some of the features i want. It isn't done, but its working. I just wanted to see if there's any improvements I could make before I start working on the next few features.

```py
from os import getenv as env
from flask import make_response
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from json_store_client import Client
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash

app = Flask('app')
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
db = Client(env("TOKEN"))

limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=lambda: auth.username(),
    default_limits=["100 per second"]
)

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    user = db.retrieve(f"users/{username}")
    try:
        if check_password_hash(user["password"], password):
            return True
    except: return False
    return False

@app.route('/regester', methods = ['POST'])
def register():
    if request.is_json: user = request.get_json()['username']
    else: user = request.form['username']
    if db.retrieve(f"users/{user}"):
        return False
    if request.is_json: db.store(f"users/{user}", { "password": generate_password_hash(request.get_json()['password'])})
    else: db.store(f"users/{user}", { "password": generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])})
    return make_response(user, 201)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'], defaults={'fullurl': ''})
@app.route('/<path:fullurl>', methods = ['GET'])
@auth.login_required
def index_get(fullurl):
    data = db.retrieve(f"data/{auth.username()}/{fullurl}")
    if data: return make_response(data, 200)
    return make_response({}, 204)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'], defaults={'fullurl': ''})
@app.route('/<path:fullurl>', methods = ['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def index_post(fullurl):
    if request.id_json: db.store(f"data/{auth.username()/{fullurl}}", request.get_json())
    else: db.store(f"data/{auth.username()}", request.form)
    return make_response(db.retrieve(f"data/{auth.username()}"), 201)

app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *Few optimization tips*

- `verify_password` function

  - avoid bare `except:` clause - at least use `except Exception:` (though it's also broad, check which exception class is most appropriate in that context)
  - a set of statements:

    ```
    try:
        if check_password_hash(user["password"], password):
            return True
    except: return False
    return False
    ```

    is an overloaded and verbose version of a more explicit logic:

    ```
    @auth.verify_password
    def verify_password(username, password):
        user = db.retrieve(f"users/{username}")
        try:
            return check_password_hash(user["password"], password)
        except Exception:
            return False
    ```
- don't overuse (or avoid entirely) multiple statements one-liners like `if <condition>: <long statement>`
- avoid writing duplicated lengthy *db* statements like:

  ```
  if request.is_json: db.store(f"users/{user}", { "password": generate_password_hash(request.get_json()['password'])})
  else: db.store(f"users/{user}", { "password": generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])})
  ```

  To fix that determine `request` data source beforehand. Optimizing **`register`** function:

  ```
  @app.route('/regester', methods = ['POST'])
  def register():
      data = request.get_json() if request.is_json else request.form
      user = data['username']
      if db.retrieve(f"users/{user}"):
          return False

      db.store(f"users/{user}", {"password": generate_password_hash(data['password'])})
      return make_response(user, 201)
  ```

  Apply this optimization technique to all remaining functions with a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the except thing before, always thought it was defaulted to `except Exception`

Comment: @HaaruunI, you're welcome

Comment: @HaaruunI: It defaults to `except BaseException`, which also includes stuff like the user pressing `Ctrl+C`.